AWS Amplify muliple login feature same as provided by gmail and facebook
I have a use case where users can switch accounts and be instantly logged in with another account without needing to enter their password if they have logged in to the application before. I've implemented simple sign-in using AWS Amplify with Auth.signIn using email and password.
Now, the challenge is to sign in a user just by using their name or email without requiring the password. How can I achieve this with AWS Amplify?
Check image same feature I need to implement.


Firstly you need to get GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID from your gcp console and set env variable.
Example code for amplify gen2:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import jwt from 'jwt-decode';
import {
  fetchAuthSession,
} from 'aws-amplify/auth';

const SignInWithGoogle = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
  // Check for an existing Google client initialization
    if (!window.google?.accounts) createScript();
  }, []);

  // Load the Google client
  const createScript = () => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client';
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    script.onload = initGsi;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  // Initialize Google client and render Google button
  const initGsi = () => {
    if (window.google?.accounts) {
      window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        callback: (response: any) => {
          customCredentialsProvider.loadFederatedLogin({
            domain: 'accounts.google.com',
            token: response.credential,
          });
          const fetchSessionResult = await fetchAuthSession(); // will return the credentials
          console.log('fetchSessionResult: ', fetchSessionResult);
        },
      });
      window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(
        document.getElementById('googleSignInButton'),
        { theme: 'outline', size: 'large' }
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button id='googleSignInButton'/>
    </div>
  );
}

https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials
Gen2 docs: https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/auth/advanced-workflows/#google-sign-in-react
For gen1 docs are here https://docs.amplify.aws/gen1/javascript/build-a-backend/auth/add-social-provider/

thanks @Grisho4ek for your input but i don't want to do it by using google account, I just want to allow user to switch previously logged in account.
